# Fixture format error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error each time i run `rake test`:

```
6) Error:

AdminTest#test_the_truth:

ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError
```

My `admins.yml` code is below:

```
one: 

 email: admin1@test.com

 password:  

two: 

  email: admin2@test.com

  password:
```

My `Admins_test.rb` is this:

```
 require 'test_helper'

 class AdminTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

 test "the truth" do
      assert true

    end

 end
```

Comment: Edit your question and format your code exactly as it is in the project. To specify that's it's a code block in SO you need to start it with a blank line then indent all code at least 4 spaces. YAML formatting is indentation sensitive and as it is now we can't see what indentation you have in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with the format of the `admins.yml` file. Try this:

```
# admins.yml
one:
  email: admin1@test.com
  password:
two:
  email: admin2@test.com
  password:
```

You can also download the `admins.yml` from [here](https://gist.github.com/rakibulislam/6a93e24d13b93c5d8674) and use it in your program. This should solve you problem.

Comment: Do you have the project on github or somewhere so that I can take a look?

Comment: but i can paste any part of the code you wanna see.

Comment: I don't see any obvious issue in your code other than the formatting of the `admins.yml` file. So, not really sure. If possible to push the code to github, then let me know the link. I will try to solve the problem Or, you can reproduce the issue in another test project and give me the link.

Comment: This answer sent me in the right direction, at the very least. I started looking at all the .yml files in the fixtures directory and found the problem